# How to find the row that has certain class name in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which has hundreds of items listed like below.

```
<tr class="available" id="trline01"><td>1</td>
<td><input type="text" class="ordItem" id="oline01" value="100"           
readonly="readonly" /></td><</tr>
<tr class="available" id="trline02"><td>2</td>
<td><input type="text" class="ordItem" id="oline02" value="20"    
readonly="readonly" /></td><</tr>
<tr class="outofstock" id="trline03"><td>3</td>
<td><input type="text" class="ordItem" id="oline03" value="0"  
readonly="readonly" /></td><</tr>
<tr class="available" id="trline04"><td>4</td>
<td><input type="text" class="ordItem" id="oline04" value="20"  
readonly="readonly" /></td><</tr>
<tr class="discount" id="trline05"><td>5</td>
<td><input type="text" class="ordItem" id="oline05" value="10"  
readonly="readonly" /></td><</tr>

....
```

I am trying to skip the "outofstock" row with the following each statement

```
$.each($('.ordItem'), function() {
    if ( !$(this).hasClass(outofstock)) {
        data[$(this).data('code')] = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

how to tr row and skip that row?

Comment: so, you only want to process  orditem's that match `.available .ordItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So select the available rows and than select the input.

```
$('tr.available .ordItem').each()
```

```js
$('tr.available .ordItem').each( function(){
   console.log(this.id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="available" id="trline01"><td>1</td>
<td><input type="text" class="ordItem" id="oline01" value="100"           
readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
<tr class="available" id="trline02"><td>2</td>
<td><input type="text" class="ordItem" id="oline02" value="20"    
readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
<tr class="outofstock" id="trline03"><td>3</td>
<td><input type="text" class="ordItem" id="oline03" value="0"  
readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
<tr class="available" id="trline04"><td>4</td>
<td><input type="text" class="ordItem" id="oline04" value="20"  
readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

and since you did not give all the details up front, you can use not() to remove the outofstock rows

```js
$('tr:not(.outofstock) .ordItem').each( function(){
   console.log(this.id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="available" id="trline01"><td>1</td>
<td><input type="text" class="ordItem" id="oline01" value="100"           
readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
<tr class="available" id="trline02"><td>2</td>
<td><input type="text" class="ordItem" id="oline02" value="20"    
readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
<tr class="outofstock" id="trline03"><td>3</td>
<td><input type="text" class="ordItem" id="oline03" value="0"  
readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
<tr class="available" id="trline04"><td>4</td>
<td><input type="text" class="ordItem" id="oline04" value="20"  
readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have a couple of more defined name for tr class. How can I just exclude ouofstock rows?                                                              $.each($('.ordItem'), function() {
 if ( !$(this).hasClass(ouofstock)) {
          data[] = $(this).val();
 }
});    I tried the above code and did not work though

Comment: Updated he question

Comment: thx, epascarello.  your answer seems legit so I will give you credit.     But somehow it does not work for me though. It does not skip the ouofstock rows....

Comment: not sure what is different than what your sample code is. Both are running here so not sure why it would be any different.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each($('.available .ordItem'), function(index, item) {
    console.log(item);
})
```

This will console all the inputs with the class '.ordItem' that are children of rows with the class '.avaliable'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to retrieve any element with whatever class is assigned to it.

$(".your-class-name")

and save it in a variable if you need to.

let someElement = $(".your-class-name")

Comment: unsure how that answers the question.